# Why does my react web app break on mobile when trying to sign an off-chain message

Tags: react, mobile, mobile-wallet-adapter, webapp

The user journey is as follows:

1. user lands on my react website
2. user connects their wallet
3. user is then prompted to "Sign this message for authentication: "
4. user signs the message and sends the signature to our server which then validates the authenticity of the message + signature

The user journey on desktop is flawless, but fails on step 3 on mobile. Instead of getting a prompt to sign a message, it redirects to a "you don't have a wallet installed" screen or breaks in some way.

Do I have to configure an additional mobile-wallet-adapter or should everything work out of the box with the wallet-adapter (because it's using mobile wallet adapter under the hood when user is on a mobile device)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this happens is because you most likely rely on `useEffect` to prompt a user to sign a message.

Like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (wallet?.publicKey) signMessageAndSendToBackend(wallet?.publicKey)
}, [wallet?.publicKey])
```

This will fail gloriously on mobile because most (if not all) mobile browsers check if the even is trusted or not. Even is not trusted if it didn't originate from a click. useEffect in this case could be a malicious script triggered on mobile browsers without users explicit approval. This flag can be found at `event.isTrusted`

What you should do is, add this logic to the `WalletButton` component so that it's done in the same click as with the `wallet.connect()`.

There is a small issue though... on mobile this isn't possible yet because this `signMessageAndSendToBackend` function requires a `mobileWallet` from the `transact` object to be able to do it. `WalletButton` component does support callbacks within the `wallet.connect` and `transact` functions so you would have to be writing your own `WalletButton` component.

I have done it and I can share the code base as per request, just make sure to contact me somehow (twitter, discord, telegram... most of my handles are `josip-volarevic` or `josipvolarevic2`). I won't share those code snippets here because one day someone might expand the `WalletButton` component and deprecate that part of my answer